# SQL date time Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Need help to get the data of particular format
We have a table which have a data which of production now we need to select the data of each day with particular time period which is differentiate between three shift A,B,C.

In our table we have a datetime column which capture's each seconds data now that data we need in shiftwise like 6am to 2pm is of A shift production count and 2pm to 10pm of shift B and 10pm to 6 am of shift C.
here i am getting the data for single day where i have written the below query which is working good.

```sql
 select distinct(count(PRD_SERIAL_NUMBER)),(select convert(date,getdate())) as date,'B' as shift_name  
from table_name
where status=02 
and LAST_UPDATED_DATE 
between (SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-dd 14:01:00.000')) and 
 (SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE()-26,'yyyy-MM-dd 22:01:00.000'))
```

refer below output image 1

[image]

Here i am getting the count for single day and for upcoming days i have solution but now the question arise is i have a past 4 Month data which i need to get in datewise and shiftwise count  and for the column prd_serial_number have duplicate entries so it should be in distinct.
please refer below image 2 for required output format

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: `(select convert(date,getdate()))` can be simplified to `getdate()` and why are you comparing a `date` column with a string value?

Comment: here i have taken date as a output of my today's date i am not comparing it with date column and its sql server 2012 database